# Creating UIButton programmatically in Swift 4 but getting error

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, uibutton

I'm trying to create a UIButton in Swift 4 but I keep getting a "Expected declaration" error in the "MyView" class when I try to call the addTarget function. I've done this same code in other classes and have never gotten the error. Am I missing something? Thanks.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func onButtonTapped()
}

class OtherViewController: UIViewController {

}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate {
    func onButtonTapped() {

        let nextViewController = OtherViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: false)

}

    var myView: MyView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView.delegate = self
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?

    let button = UIButton()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped),for: .touchUpInside)

    func buttonTapped() {
        self.delegate?.onButtonTapped()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot addTarget or call any method in the class space , this space is for declartion as the error suggests .

to fix this you can do either this

```
let button:UIButton =
{
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped),for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()
```

Or

```
   let button:UIButton = UIButton()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped),for: .touchUpInside)

}
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

in both cases you must add @objc annotation to the buttonTapped function because selectors must refer to an @objc function .

so it will be like this

```
   @objc func buttonTapped(){}
```

Also you need to add this button to the view on order for it to be drawn to the screen .

```
view.addSubView(button)
```